# Blowfish and Crypt Successful Example?

Tags: php, encryption, blowfish

I'm reading up on protecting passwords and want to get feedback on if my code is correct. I'm trying to use blowfish and `crypt()` together to prevent anyone from decrypting passwords. Also, I have a question. When I store the password, I assume I will have to also store the variable `$string` so that I can use it again to verify the user when he signs in, correct?

```
function unique_md5() {
  mt_srand(microtime(true)*100000 + memory_get_usage(true));
  return md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
}

//unique_md5 returns a random 16 character string

$string = '$2a$07$' . unique_md5();

$password = 'password';

$password = trim($password);

$protected_password = crypt($password, $string); 

//then store the variables $string and $protected_password into the database
```

Comment: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/php_blowfish.asp - Google

Comment: `$cleartext` I assume is what is being encrypted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blowfish takes a 22 character string for it's salt (that's not including the type and the cost parameter). MD5 returns a **32** character string, which is not accepted by `crypt_blowfish`. Use proper salts.

Comment: So if I can return the MD5 by cutting off the last or first 10 character strings, would that be acceptable, or would that eliminate the randomness of MD5?

Comment: Providing a longer salt will use only the initial 22 characters automatically, no need for special processing.

Comment: Just to verify, the type and the cost parameter you refered to is this string `$2a$07$`, correct?

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to store the salt with the encrypted password, as the encrypted password is returned to you with the salt already prepended. When you verify if a plaintext password matches a crypted password, you only need to check if `$crypted_password == crypt($plaintext_password, $crypted_password)`.